# How to fix "reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer" warning

Tags: c++, reference, xcode6

Xcode 6.3 (beta) gives me new warnings, any suggestions how to fix the problem? I don't think removing the check completely as void is a correct answer, since in some cases "camera" has been NULL and caused crashing later elsewhere.

> Reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code; comparison may be assumed to always evaluate to false

Here's the code. How else could I verify camera exists?

```cpp
Camera& camera = sceneEngine->camera();
// FIXME: this triggers an undefined-bool-conversion warning in Xcode 6.3 BETA
if (&camera == NULL) return;
```

And the related method from SceneEngine:

```cpp
// HEADER
class SceneEngine
{
public:
    Camera& camera();
protected:
    Camera camera_;
}

// CPP
Camera& SceneEngine::camera() {
    return camera_;
}
```

Comment: If you have a `Camera&`, then the camera exists or you have undefined behaviour. No buts.

Comment: So you suggest that to get rid of the warning I should just remove the check and handle crashing (when camera is NULL) in some other way?

Comment: References are never supposed to be `NULL`, they are meant to always point to an actual object, unless you are invoking undefined behaviour somewhere like forcing an object to exist at address 0 as demonstrated in R Sahu's answer. Either this assertion shouldn't be there or you should be using pointers instead.

Comment: @JOM How could camera possibly be NULL?

Comment: @immibis I was handed over a huge pile of code, still trying to figure it out :) This code was ok earlier, but LLVM with Xcode 6.3 is more strict. I like it, but this case is tricky.

Comment: @JOM you should probably find out where the camera might become NULL, and fix that. Alternatively, change the references to pointers throughout.

Comment: In your case the compiler is simply telling you that the condition will be always be true like everybody said. However, IMO, there are other cases where this should be allowed (overaloaded `operator&`). `gcc` accepts this with no problem, and you can make `clang` accept it using the option `-Wno-undefined-bool-conversion`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `camera` object is returned by *reference*, it **cannot** be null, since references always point to an actual existing object.

So if you take the address of a reference variable, it can't be null, since it's pointing to a valid object anyway.

Just use the return value without any null check.

**PS.** If the function returns a reference to a non-existing object (e.g. null), that's just undefined behavior.

**Solution:**

If `camera()` needs to be able to return null at some point, then change its return type to `Camera*` to be able to return a null pointer.

Else — `camera()` never returns null, i.e. it always returns a reference to a valid object —, your null check is not needed and that's what the error message is saying.

Comment: You are right: either I have to change interface or make sure camera would always exist. I'll choose to change return type from Camera& to Camera* since the rest of code seems to expect that. Creating a missing camera would be a more risky task. Thanx for several solution ideas!

Answer (score 5):

Since the language standard defines that you have undefined behavior in the moment that you have a `NULL` reference, the compiler is allowed to optimize away your condition entirely. Consequently, this code useless. The warning informs you about this.

To silence the warning, you need to write your code in a way that you ensure that you do not generate `NULL` references in the first place. I. e., before you write code like this:

```
void bar(Camera& cam);
void foo(Camera* cam) {
    bar(*cam);
}
```

you need to check the pointer before you convert it into a reference:

```
void bar(Camera& cam);
void foo(Camera* cam) {
    if(cam) bar(*cam);    //this works as desired
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your line

```
if (&camera == NULL) return;
```

we can ask: When will that statement be true? The answer is only when `camera` is bound to a dereferenced NULL pointer.

If you had a clear case of bad code like:

```
Camera* cameraPtr = NULL;
Camera& camera = *cameraPtr;
```

the conditional of the above `if` statement will evaluate to `true`. If it is possible for `camera` to be bound to such a dereferenced pointer, the `if` statement has some value. Otherwise, it has no value and the compiler is warning you about that.

You asked:

> How else could I verify camera exists?

When a function returns a reference, you have to assume that the function returns a valid `Camera` object and proceed to use it. Remove the `if` line.

Comment: `Camera& camera = *cameraPtr;` is undefined behaviour when `cameraPtr` is NULL.

Comment: @immibis, I understand that to be the case in well defined code. I am presenting a clear case of bad code.

Comment: Okay, just understand that `Camera& camera = *cameraPtr;` is allowed to crash your program.